# Dynamics 365: Call javascript when clicking on Assign button

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to call a javascript function when clicking on Assign button to filter results of assign to User or Team field. Is there any example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog displayed through the built-in Assign button is not customizable.

However, there is a way to achieve your requirement in a relatively easy way. First customize the ribbon by hiding the built-in Assign button.

Then add the owner field to the form. This lookup field can be customized and you can limit the choice users have to either systemuser or team records.

Answer (score 1):

you can build a dialog and call it from ribbon. Check link https://github.com/phuocle/crmdialog

Answer (score 0):

The Assign functionality is out of the box, and no javascript can be executed inside that window.